# Reset TextView position in row of Listview for Android Application

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using ListView to display some data. The data is shown in TextView. String length which is shown can vary. so the textview which is shown changes its positions depending upon the length of the string. The problem I am facing is 
Suppose there are 5 rows. For Row 3 if the text is long, the position of textview showing the text adjusts to show the content. However, textview positions of other rows also changes even if the text is smaller. This has something to do with ListView row caching **I am not able to figure out how to reset the row.**

Row Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/text_margin_bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_content3" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/id2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_content3" />
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/text_margin_bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/id3"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_content3" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/id4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_content3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**GetView Code**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            ShowData metaData = getItem(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.id1 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.id1);
                holder.id2 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.id2);
                holder.id3 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.id3);
                holder.id3 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.id4);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            convertView.invalidate();
            holder.id1.setText(metaData.id1);
            holder.id2.setText(metaData.id2);
            holder.id3.setText(metaData.id3);
            holder.id4.setText(metaData.id4);
            return convertView;
        }
```

How to reset the listview row?

Comment: can you provide an image of the row you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You might try calling `requestLayout()` on the `TextView`s after you've set their text.

Comment: @Mike M: Thanks that did the trick. Please post this as answer. I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, your `TextView`s are sizing vertically due to the `wrap_content` values for their `layout_height`s. It seems that when `View`s are recycled in `ListView`s (and, most likely, all `AdapterView`s), no layout is automatically triggered, so the `TextView`s will retain their previous heights. Calling `requestLayout()` on them will trigger a layout event, during which the `TextView`s will adjust to their new contents.